# При подключении fancybox, что значит v=2.1.5, v=1.0.5, v=1.0.6 ..?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

При подключении fancybox, что значит v=2.1.5, v=1.0.5, v=1.0.6 ..? Например, 
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите, пример кода. Значить это может что угодно. Более вероятно, что это номер версии.

Comment: привела пример. или еще что-то нужно?

Comment: Код должен быть текстом, а не картинкой...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это версия скрипта. По факту наличие этого параметра необязательно. Но часто такой "трюк" используется для того чтобы избежать проблем с кешированием.

У пользователей кешируется файл `jquery.fancybox.pack.js` и если параметр не указывается, то при обновлении версии файла на сервере у некоторых пользователей может подгружаться предыдущая версия файла из кеша. А использование такого параметра позволяет избежать потенциальных проблем.

А так практика очень полезная. Можно так же указывать некоторый параметр и для своих файлов со скриптами. Особенно если в них были внесены довольно серьезные изменения.

Comment: ооочень благодарна, спасибо за подробный ответ.